# mysql query timeout - "Default" outputted to browser

Tags: php, mysql

I have an application written in PHP which contains a function to perform a complex MySQL query to gather statistics and export it as CSV. Usually the process takes a good 20-30 seconds to complete due to the complexity of the query but I can live with this as it's just one query once a week.

The issue I have is now and again the server just appears to timeout with the word '**Default**' outputted to the browser and nothing else

I'm sure this isn't being set/printed in the application logic because I wrote it myself and after looking at the database class I searched every single file in the application for the word Default with no results

I'm also pretty sure it can't be output from the MySQL server because it can't directlty print output without going through PHP can it?

What could be causing this? I'm thinking the only function that could be printing it is my mysql_query() function. Obviously my aim is to optimize the query to stop the timeout but I'd like to find out what is ouputting text as I don't like errors/messages like that being displayed to our users

Comment: Does PHP have something similar to exceptions? Maybe this is what the default handler does, and you need to override it somehow. Or set a higher timeout for the database operation :-)

Comment: You may try setting your timeout limit to a higher value in both php and mysql configurations. Output buffering can also be used as a debug tool to check the reason behind that output.

Comment: I will set a higher timeout but I'm still curious as to what function/process is outputting 'Default' because I supress all error messages from being output and just log them

Comment: @diegoperini The system uses output buffering as standard anyway to process a template called from the controller. I wonder if ob_get_contents() is the culprit...

Comment: I would suggest setting up a test version, setting the timeout to something tiny (so it will occur every time) and then hacking the code around to find the source of the problem. Beyond that I would like to see your actual query and the tables and explains.